# Console app in C# fails to execute as soon as data types in Autodesk libraries are used

Tags: c#, console-application, autocad, autocad-plugin

I'm developing some AutoCAD add-ons in C# and I was hoping to work/debug my classes in a console application first until I'm ready to implement the functionality inside AutoCAD. /dot net libraries cannot be unloaded and one needs to restart/reload acad each time the code is modified/
Interestingly I'm finding that as soon as I declare a variable which uses an autocad data type my console app refuses to run and Im presented with a "the application is in break mode" screen in visual studio. For example this code does not run:

```
  using System;
  using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
  namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");
            Point2d p;            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Trying this referencing Autodesk C3D 2016 dll libraries. Does anyone have an explanation of what is going on here and/or any workarounds?
thnks

Comment: Can you run a C# app without the Autodesk included?  Do you get the same error?  If so, try this:  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/13290/uwp-breakpoint-doesnt-break-into-source-code-makin.html   The solution is approx 80% down the page

Comment: Yes, as soon as I comment out the Point2d line the app runs as expected

Comment: Try two more things:  instantiate p.  If it still has the same error, try removing your reference, clean and build, then add the reference back, clean and build.

Comment: No luck! Still getting the same problem - no acad objects - the app builds and runs fine. As soon as I add a reference/instance to the acad libraries - "..break mode".

Comment: What if you use a different object from the Autodesk library?  If you change to release mode does it build and run?  If so try Tools -> Option -> Debugging. Make sure Enabled Just My Code is unchecked.  If that works, try "Go to definition" on Point2d and see if it tries to show you the class and check for break points.

Comment: The AutoCAD libraries depend tightly with AutoCAD, and most are wrappers around the C++ classes embedded in the binaries. You basically can't use any of them outside of the running application.

Comment: yup....I think I just found the answer here:
http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2017/FRA/?guid=GUID-C8C65D7A-EC3A-42D8-BF02-4B13C2EA1A4B

Basically this behaviour is by design unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The AutoCAD .NET API is designed to run in-process only.
AutoCAD .NET libraries can only be used to build plug-ins (DLL) which have to be loaded in AutoCAD for execution.

Answer (score 1):

To debug your AutoCAD Add-On code, you need to create a C# Class Library Project referencing the Autodesk CAD 2016 Sdk Libraries, and encapsulate your code on public method that declared with [**CommandMethodAttribute**](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-F77E8FE0-8034-4704-93BD-F717608F8223-htm.html). With this method declared with CommandMethod it's the be your trigger between the AutoCAD prompt command and your Add-On code.

```
public class AcadCommands
{
    [CommandMethod("TriggerCmd")]
    public void TriggerCommand
    {
        Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        ed.WriteMessage("Hi");
        Point2d p;
    }
}
```

Note: at your Visual Studio Project Properties, you need to configure to start debug pointed to acad.exe and when the AutoCAD applications starts, open some DWG and prompt the ["**NETLOAD**"](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-D954BCC1-C4F0-488B-8F60-1D02D68940E0-htm.html) command to include your debbugable compiled DLL from your VS Project to AutoCAD Application context.
[image]